# apache query string rewrite rules

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, query-string, redirect

I am setting up Query string redirect :

`expo.com/en/general/campaigns/on-second-thought.html?slide=ost-2016-tank` to 
`expo.com/en/general/campaigns/on-second-thought/ost-2016-tank.html`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)expo\.com
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} slide=ost-2016-tank
RewriteRule  ^/en/general/campaigns/on-second-thought.html?$  http://www.expo.com/en/general/campaigns/on-second-thought/ost-2016-tank.html [R=301,L,NC]
```

redirect happening but its appending ?slide=ost-2016-tank like below

```
http://www.expo.com/en/general/campaigns/on-second-thought/ost-2016-tank.html?slide=ost-2016-tank
```

`slide=ost-2016-tank` parameter is added to redirected page

Answer (score 1):

Since your rule does not define a new query string, the default behavior of Apache is to copy the old query string to the new URL. To get rid of it, append a `?` to the address you rewrite/redirect to:

```
 RewriteRule  ^/en/general/campaigns/on-second-thought\.html?$  http://www.expo.com/en/general/campaigns/on-second-thought/ost-2016-tank.html? [R=301,L,NC]
```

Or, for Apache >= 2.4, you can also use the flag QSD (Query String Discard):

```
RewriteRule  ^/en/general/campaigns/on-second-thought\.html?$  http://www.expo.com/en/general/campaigns/on-second-thought/ost-2016-tank.html [R=301,L,NC,QSD]
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add a blank query string when redirecting:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)expo\.com
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^slide=(ost-2016-tank)$
RewriteRule  ^(/?en/general/campaigns/on-second-thought)\.(html)$ $1/%1.$2? [R=301,L,NC]
```

No need to mention `http://expo.com` again when redirecting. It'll automatically redirect to the same hostname because of `R` flag. No need to repeat same strings over and over. Using match groups and referencing them later works.

Your pattern had `.html?$` in it, which actually means that it'll match `.html` as well as `.htm`. You do not receive query strings in `RewriteRule` context.